# Why do I get the error "Unknown column 'comp.id' in 'where clause'" when I try to insert values from one MySQL table into another?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have two tables. The first table is called `test` and has 3 columns (`id`, `Name`, and `Mobile`). The second table is called `comp` and also has 3 columns (`id`, `Nave`, and `Mobile`). I want to insert values into the `Nave` column of table `comp` using values from the `Name` column of table `test`. I tried the following:

```
my $sql="INSERT INTO comp (Nave) SELECT Name from test WHERE test.id=comp.id";
```

But I got an error:

> Unknown column 'comp.id' in 'where clause'

Note that both tables are in the same database. How can I fix this?

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to insert new rows or update existing rows. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to update existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to update existing rows in table comp:

```
update comp c
join test t on t.id = c.id
set c.Nave = t.Name
```

Comment: yes I want to update existing rows in table comp: Thanks